# Python finding all instances of the word bin and counting it

Tags: python

I'm trying to analyse a log file and extract some information from it as part of an assignment. I'm having some trouble with the first one in which i have to find all instances of the bin user and show how many times they have logged in.

What's happening right now is that when I run the code it loads the log file as it should do but nothing else. So can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

This is what i got so far

```
f=open('auth.log' , 'r')
print f.read()

counter_bin=0

for line in f:
    if "bin" in line:
    counter_bin+=1

    f.close()
    print "Total number of bin: ",counter_bin
```

Comment: What kind of trouble?

Comment: Please reindent your code, it makes no sense now

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the broken indention.

Comment: You open a file, read it completely (statement `print f.read()`) and eventually you iterate on the lines in the file... you are iterating on nothing and nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
bin_lines = 0
with open('auth.log') as log:
    for line in log:
        # logic to determine if line was from bin
        bin_lines += 1

print('bin made %d log lines' % bin_lines)
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it an academic task or a real problem?
In latter case you may use special tool for this - `grep`.

Like so:

```
    $ grep -c bin auth.log
    1234
```

1234 just for example - you'll get real number of occurrences `bin` in file.